# Getting compilation errors whn included a third party library

Tags: c, makefile

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "flite.h"
cst_voice *register_cmu_us_kal();
int main()
{
 cst_voice *v;
 cst_wave *w;
 char *text = "Hello world programming";

 //Initialising the flite variables used
 flite_init();
 w = new_wave();

 v = register_cmu_us_kal(NULL);
 flite_text_to_speech(text,v,"hello_wave");

 if(cst_wave_load_riff(w,"hello_wave")!=CST_OK_FORMAT){
  printf("\nCompare_wave:Can read file or wrong format!\n");
 }
 else{
  play_wave(w);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
all:compile \
  ./compile
compile:eg1.o
  gcc -o $@ eg1.o 
eg1.o:eg1.c $(LIBS_DIR) $(INC_DIR) $(LIBS)
  gcc -c $<
LIBS_DIR = -L /home/b/flite-1.4-release/build/i386-linux-gnu/lib
INC_DIR = -I /home/b/flite-1.4-relase/include
LIBS = -lflite_cmu_us_slt -lflite -lflite_cmulex -lflite_cmu_time_awb -lflite_cmu_us_kal16 -lflite_cmu_us_kal -lflite_cmu_usenglish
INCLUDE:
clean:
  rm -f *.o






I tried by giving he library and header file paths as LIBS_DIR = ../build/i386-linux-gnu/lib and INC_DIR = ../include
```

I tried the folowing c program by including a third party library. This program an a makefile is located in b\flite-1.4-release\Learnin_though_example folder. Th flite libraries are located in b\flite-1.4-release\build\i386-linux-gnu\lib and the header files are in b\flite-1.4-release\include .

I assume that i have given the makefile th correct path to search for the files. But its not identifyin it and i'm gettin an error as,

```
make clean all
rm -f *.o
gcc -c eg1.c
eg1.c:2:19: error: flite.h: No such file or directory
eg1.c:3: error: expected â€˜=â€™, â€˜,â€™, â€˜;â€™, â€˜asmâ€™ or â€˜__attribute__â€™ before â€˜*â€™ token
eg1.c: In function â€˜mainâ€™:
eg1.c:6: error: â€˜cst_voiceâ€™ undeclared (first use in this function)
eg1.c:6: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
eg1.c:6: error: for each function it appears in.)
eg1.c:6: error: â€˜vâ€™ undeclared (first use in this function)
eg1.c:7: error: â€˜cst_waveâ€™ undeclared (first use in this function)
eg1.c:7: error: â€˜wâ€™ undeclared (first use in this function)
eg1.c:17: error: â€˜CST_OK_FORMATâ€™ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [eg1.o] Error 1
```

Please help me understand what is the mistake i'm doing

**EDITED:**

I modiied th makefile as per matt's guidance:

```
all:compile
compile:eg1.o
  gcc $(INC_DIR) $(LIB_DIR) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS) 
eg1.o:eg1.c
  gcc $(INC_DIR) -o $@ -c $^
LIBS_DIR = -L../build/i386-linux-gnu/lib
INC_DIR = -I../include
LIBS = -lflite -lflite_cmulex -lflite_cmu_time_awb -lflite_cmu_us_kal16 -lflite_cmu_us_kal -lflite_cmu_usenglish -lflite_cmu_us_slt
clean:
  rm -f *.o
```

but i'm getting ifferent error whn compiled with the command "make clean all" as,

```
rm -f *.o
gcc -I../include -o eg1.o -c eg1.c
gcc -I../include  -o compile eg1.o -lflite -lflite_cmulex -lflite_cmu_time_awb -lflite_cmu_us_kal16 -lflite_cmu_us_kal -lflite_cmu_usenglish -lflite_cmu_us_slt 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lflite
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

**EDITED:**

```
rm -f *.o
gcc -I../include -o eg1.o -c eg1.c
gcc -I../include -L../build/i386-linux-gnu/lib -o compile eg1.o -lflite -lflite_cmulex -lflite_cmu_time_awb -lflite_cmu_us_kal16 -lflite_cmu_us_kal -lflite_usenglish -lflite_cmu_us_slt -lflite_cmu_us_rms 
../build/i386-linux-gnu/lib/libflite.so: undefined reference to `sin'
../build/i386-linux-gnu/lib/libflite.so: undefined reference to `exp'
../build/i386-linux-gnu/lib/libflite.so: undefined reference to `sqrt'
../build/i386-linux-gnu/lib/libflite.so: undefined reference to `log'
../build/i386-linux-gnu/lib/libflite.so: undefined reference to `fmod'
../build/i386-linux-gnu/lib/libflite.so: undefined reference to `pow'
```

Comment: You define `LIBS_DIR` but use `LIB_DIR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your makefile is, I'm afraid to say, completely broken.

The basic Makefile syntax is:

```
target: pre-requisite(s)
<tab>Stuff to do to build target from pre-reqs (if required)
```

So this is wrong, `eg1.o` can't be a pre-requisite for building itself.

```
compile:eg1.o
  gcc -o eg1.o
```

You should have:

```
eg1.o: eg1.c
  gcc $(INC_DIR) -o $@ -c $^
```

(`$@` is the target, `$^` all the pre-reqs.)

Then you can:

```
myexe: eg1.o
  gcc $(INC_DIR) $(LIBS_DIR) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

This will produce `myexe` from `eg1.o`. And your `all` rule should be `all: myexe`, with no recipe (no commands), and at the top as you have it.

Then you've got your include directories and library directories mixed up. `-I` is for include paths, `-L` for library paths.

Place your variable definitions before the rules, that's more common/usual. And don't put a space between `-L`/`-I` and the path that follows it.

Comment: Hi mat, That really helped me to reduce all the bigger mistakes i did in writing a makefile. Thank u. But i could not make it with zero errors.please see the edit.

Comment: `LIB_DIR` is not the same thing as `LIBS_DIR`. Edited my answer to fit your variables. Please make sure you understand stuff you copy/paste.

Comment: Thanks Mat. I understood things you have explained clearly. I corrected the typo error. But still i'm geting another set of errors as "Undefined references".Please see the edit

Comment: All those functions are in the math library, link with `-lm`. (Please read the man pages for the functions you use, this is specified there.) (Add `-lm` and the _end_ of the libraries list.)

Comment: Thank u so much Mat for the patience you have taken to help a beginner like me in understanding the problems.

Answer (score 1):

The [include directories](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) to search is specified by `-I` flag, not `-L`.

Change:

```
LIBS_DIR = -I /home/b/flite-1.4-release/build/i386-linux-gnu/lib
INC_DIR = -L /home/b/flite-1.4-relase/include
```

to:

```
LIBS_DIR = -L /home/b/flite-1.4-release/build/i386-linux-gnu/lib
INC_DIR = -I /home/b/flite-1.4-relase/include
```