# failed to open audio device /dev/dsp

Tags: c, unix

[Getting compilation errors whn included a third party library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247661/getting-compilation-errors-whn-included-a-third-party-library/9247734#9247734)

This is the same example as the above link. When i tried to execute the executable "compile" its telling "failed to open audio device /dev/dsp"

```
b@cheetah-desktop:~/flite-1.4-release/Learning_through_examples$ ./compile 
./compile: error while loading shared libraries: libflite.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
b@cheetah-desktop:~/flite-1.4-release/Learning_through_examples$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/b/flite-1.4-release/build/i386-linux-gnu/lib/
b@cheetah-desktop:~/flite-1.4-release/Learning_through_examples$ ./compile 
oss_audio: failed to open audio device /dev/dsp
```

Comment: Does `/dev/dsp` exist on your system? (my guess is that it does not)

Answer (score 6):

It is trying to talk to your sound card (during compilation??). What is your system? Most new Linux distributions don't provide the OSS (open sound system) compatibility layer, because access to the OSS sound device `/dev/dsp` was exclusive to one program at time only. If you have PulseAudio running, you can wrap the call using `padsp` (see its manpage) or (which is the same) `export LD_PRELOAD=libpulsedsp.so` and the run your program. `libpulsedsp.so` will  catch opens of `/dev/dsp` and emuate OSS transparently.

Answer (score 2):

Your user doesn't have rights to open /dev/dsp.

Do a `chmod o+rw /dev/dsp` or add permissions to the group of your user.

Comment: Not in this case. The error is clearly ENOENT - no file found. As the error message shows. Well okay that's for another file. But that's also relevant. Most likely the same goes for `/dev/dsp` too.